# How to embed Dynamic Static Bing Maps into webpage

Tags: php, mysql, html, bing-maps, bing

I am creating a website where I store a location in a database and I was wondering if I could use bing maps to show that location on a map. You may be asking yourself what is a Dynamic Static map, right? Well what I mean is that the page loads the location from a database and then loads that location from Bing Maps but that but that content is not moveable, zoomable or any other interaction including showing the Bing logo(copyright I don't mind), kinda like an image almost. How would I go about doing this and also, if I use the free version of the bing maps api and my site IS password protected, how much do they enforce the rule that my site can't be password protected? Thanks for any help.

BTW; I would be loading the information from a mysql database through php so I would like to be able to use the bing map api through php, if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two options:

1) Using the bing maps javascript API V7 set the mapoption disableUserInput to true:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427603.aspx

2) Use the bing maps imagery rest service and request a static image of the location you want, which you could cache on your own server:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701724.aspx

And both of these options are technology agnostic so can be used in any programming language / framework

Comment: Ok thanks. I was doing a little research and I am working with the rest framework.